# Try-Catch error handiling in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, try-catch

I have one doubt regarding **Try-Catch** block.

Below is my code

```
 private void PopulateDDL()
    {
        try
        {
            if (my condition)
            {
                code
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logerror(ex);
        }
    }
```

Which **Catch** block will be executed if error for below code
else

```
        {
            throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
        }
```

Comment: The only catch block you have defined? Was there meant to be more than one?

Comment: other CATCH block means parent method i.e from which this method called

Comment: If error occurs in `PopulateDLL()` method, its catch block will be called. If the error is somewhere in the parent method other than `PopulateDLL()`, parent method's catch block will be called.

Comment: If possible, post the parent method also. It will make us able to understand the scenario more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx):

> When an exception is thrown, the common language runtime (CLR) looks
>   for the catch statement that handles this exception. If the currently
>   executing method does not contain such a catch block, the CLR looks at
>   the method that called the current method, and so on up the call
>   stack. If no catch block is found, then the CLR displays an unhandled
>   exception message to the user and stops execution of the program.

The catch block you have defined:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    RaiseWebError(ex);
}
```

will be executed first for the exception `throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);`

If `RaiseWebError` re-throws the exception this will then be handled by the next try-catch block found futher up the call stack (i.e. the parent method you refer to). But if `RaiseWebError` handles the exception in some way (perhaps by logging the exception) execution will continue after the first try-catch.